# Blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin with MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, file, upload

I can't integrate MySQL with the blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin... I read the tutorial in https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration

but I can't do this...

Do you have a package download with Jquery File upload with MySQL?

Thanks..

Comment: please show us what have you tried with your code and possibly what error you're getting? Do mention in your question..

Comment: `but I can't do this` is not a proper problem statement and is meaningless

Answer (score -1):

@Cfc First Off, "Can't" makes me want to puke. 2ndly, I am a novice programmer whom has come upon this task and I will say It IS indeed very daunting looking but once you get over the deer in the headlights look it starts coming into focus but you DO HAVE TO TRY at which point you'll see it is pretty well laid out in the tutorial you linked to. It could be better documented that's for sure, but this is your chance to do something w/o having someone hold your hand every step. Im learning all the "Clues" you'll need actually seem to be present. You just gotta TRY